# KeyAdapter not working

Tags: java, swing, input, jframe

I just wrote some small code trying to get my KeyEvent manager to work.

As you can see i created a JFrame and added the gameComponent which is an object of the Game class. I set the JPanel focusable and requested the focus. Then a KeyAdapter called TAdapter was set as KeyAdapter. You can see the class at the very and of the code it extends a KeyAdapter and the method keyPressed().

I told the program to print "pressed" to my console when a key is pressed but nothing happens.

I cannot figure out what I've done wrong, maybe somebody sees some bugs i don't see by myself?

Any help is appreciated

Thanks in advance

```
    public class Game extends JPanel {

public static final int WIDTH = 320;
public static final int HEIGHT = 240;
public static final int SCALE = 3;

public Game() {
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Game gameComponent = new Game();
    Dimension size = new Dimension(WIDTH*SCALE, HEIGHT*SCALE);
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Invaders");

    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(size);
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setResizable(false);
    frame.add(gameComponent);
}

public class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        System.out.println("Pressed");
    }
}   
}
```

Comment: Tested your code and it works perfectly well.

Comment: perhaps the button is obfuscated by something or the window is unfocused?

Comment: Probably it might be a problem with my keyboard. I am writing the code on my Surface Pro with the attached Type Cover and on my other pc this code always worked like a charm. thanks

Comment: camickr answer is right , if you read api it say that you dont have to call `requestFocus` instead use `requestFocusInWindow()` but won't do anything and returns false cause a panel is not  `focusable` , so instead of that use `KeyBinding`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
requestFocus();
```

The proper method to use is:

```
requestFocusInWindow();
```

although even that method won't work because those methods can only be invoked on a visible component. When you create the component it is not yet visible so get rid of that line of code.

The main problem with your code is that you add the component to the frame AFTER the frame is visible. The code should be something like:

```
frame.add(gameComponent);
frame.setSize(size);
frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame.setResizable(false);
frame.setVisible(true);
```

That is `setVisible(true)` should be the last thing you do after all components have been added to the frame.

Finally you should not even be using a KeyListener. Swing was designed to be using with [Key Bindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html). You will not have focus issues when you use Key Bindings properly.